# Unique field in email?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to search a unique field attribute of header or any part of an email which remain static and same through out the entire email thread?
mean It should be match when I start a new email and then someone reply me on that email, then again I reply to same person with same email, and that person reply back to me on email.Which field will I can a unique to identify this email?

Comment: Message-Id, later found in References. Unless someone wants to do it differently.

Comment: @arnt -but Message-Id is changed for same email when some one reply on our email. I want to updated first once means get reply of email, it should uniquely identify the entire email thread. any other alternative to do so? , problem with Message-Id is that if I have saved against my first email reply, then after if I got other reply on same email it will not match message-id because it gets changes.so anything unique so it will updated same email in database?

Comment: The original message-id is later found in references.

Comment: There is no such field universally supported.  As @arnt says, you need to follow threading via Message-Id, In-Reply-To, and References headers.  Or, if you're lucky, you'll use a server that natively supports threading.  Gmail has a special X-GM-THRID attribute which is the same for all messages in a thread.